# How to style every element in a theme?

Tags: theming

I created a theme from scratch and I didnt make a lot of changes to the `theme template` files which listed as below:

> - block.tpl.php
> - html.tpl.php
> - node.tpl.php
> - node--article.tpl.php
> - page.tpl.php
> - page--front.tpl.php
> - views-view.tpl.php
> - views-view-fields.tpl.php

A lot of styling that I made with `HTML/CSS` was missed up when I start creating contents and didn't appear as I expected.

Below code is used for getting the whole content, but how am I able to break it into artic title, article meta, article content body?

```
print render($content);
```

So I would like to know how am I able to edit the `PHP` files and giving styles to each element? Also some of elements that are specific for home page and category pages are shown into the article pages, so how shall I fix that too?

**EDIT:**
here is title's code from `page.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if ($title): ?><h1 class="pageTitle"><?php print $title; ?></h1><?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

and that's the title code from `node--article.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
<h3 class="postTitle"><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

But still all articles getting its title styling from `page.tpl.php` and it is staying outisde of the div that I specified for the `node--article.tpl.php` file. So how to fix that?

Comment: you are in right track, all you need to do is look some more theming articles. `html.tpl.php` is for generic layout like `<html>` tag, title, metatags, _(including js/css in soem case if you are not satisfied with THEME.info)_ etc.

Comment: @Kareem I suppose `page-tpl.php`and `node--article-tpl.php`are typos? The correct file extension is `.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad. As I understand it, you want to know how the [Drupal theming system](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme) works ;)

If you want to style the output of a node then have a look at the [default node template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) in order to find out, what variables are available.

Before creating a theme from scratch I find it highly advisable though, to look through the default core themes and some more popular contrib themes in order to understand different approaches. If it's only about some styling changes, you could also use a minimalistic theme and change it according to your needs.

> A lot of styling that I made with HTML/CSS was missed up when I start creating contents and didn't appear as I expected.

Is it possible that you use a wysiwyg editor for content editing and that this interferes with the CSS in your theme?

**Edit:**
The title in `node--article.tpl.php` will only be printed if the node is not shown as a full node (but in teaser view), e.g. no visiting `/node/NID`. That's controlled by the $page variable. Once again, please look at the default node template: [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) to see what variables are available and what they mean. If you visit `/node/NID` then the default behavior in Drupal is that the page title (the one used in `page.tpl.php` is set to the node title and displayed in the page template, not in the node template. You can change that off course, but you have to adapt the display logic inside the templates to match your needs. You could try something like the following.

In `page.tpl.php`:

```
<?php if (!isset($node) || $node->type != 'article'): ?>
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <?php if ($title): ?><h1 class="pageTitle"><?php print $title; ?></h1><?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will print the page title only if you are not on a node page or if the node is not of type article.

In `node--article.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<h3 class="postTitle"><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h3>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

This will always print the nodes title whenever `node--article.tpl.php` is used, regardless if the node is displayed as a full page or as a teaser view.

Comment: I wanted to know how to rename the default theme classes and ids to what I used with HTML I've created. So I be able to give them different styling.

Comment: Can you update your question with some code? It's kind of difficult to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please check now...

Comment: @Kareem I have updated my answer.

Comment: It worked exactly how I wanted it but drupal came with error in this line: <?php if (!$node || $node->type != 'article'): ?>

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: node in include() (line 48 of .././page.tpl.php)

Comment: @Kareem Ok, I have updated the answer.

Comment: IF I edit this code will it help to show things (like Feature slider) on pages but not articles, will it help?

Comment: Might help, but I can only repeat what I already said: Take the time to learn how the [Drupal theming system](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme) works. To display specific pieces of information you would probably use fields or the node hooks to add output to the `$content`variable. That output needs to be assembled, processed, preprocessed, themed and then added to the node. That way logic stays out of the theme layer and can be encapsulated into modules. A lot of display logic can be controlled in the dackend too, depending on the modules you have installed. (Just throwing keywords)